# Do I need a passport to fly from UK to Bulgaria through Istanbul?

Tags: passports, eu, isl, eu-id-card

Tuesday I'm travelling from Birmingham, UK to Sofia, Bulgaria. The flight is with Turkish Airlines and it is a connecting flight which means it will go from Birmingham to Istanbul, and then to Sofia. Since I lost my passport I am not sure whether I could go through the Istanbul Airport.

Normally, if I were to travel directly from UK to Bulgaria I would only need my personal ID card since both countries are in the EU, but I'm not entirely sure if I could go through the Turkish airport with my ID card.

Answer (score 1):

The following is without guarantee and the airline may still deny you boarding if it thinks a passport should be held.

If the airport in Istanbul is Ataturk airport (IST) you [should not need to clear Turkish immigration](http://www.turkishairlines.com/en-int/travel-information/baggage/transit-transfer-passenger-procedures) - thus you should be OK with your national ID only. The [website of the airport](http://www.ataturkairport.com/en-EN/preflight/Pages/Transfer.aspx) does not give any information for international to international transport.

For reference: if immigration procedures were required, a passport would be required - unless you're a national of one of the countries nationals of which are [allowed entry to Turkey with a national ID](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa).

Comment: UK does not do National/EU ID card, so OP can not (just) be UK national.

Comment: @Willeke good point - I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am Bulgarian I was just studying here in the UK.

Comment: @greyshade I somewhat doubt this answer to be true. What if OP decided to leave the international transfer area at IST? He would show up at immigration and the airline ultimately get a fine.

Comment: Even if it works, traveling to a foreign (non-EU anyway) country without a passport seems like a bad plan. If anything goes wrong, such as your connecting flight being cancelled and another one not available for some time, you'd be stuck in the airport with no ability to leave and go to a hotel.

Comment: @mts that's why I cautioned that the airline may still deny boarding..

Comment: @ZachLipton how is this different from a case where airside international transit requires no visa, while entering the country would? not being able to enter the country while being somewhere for airside transit is a perfectly normal case and would you try to show up at immigration you would be in trouble not the airline

Comment: @greyshade There's no guarantee, but countries can and do waive visa requirements when travelers end up stranded due to circumstances entirely outside of their control (this happened on a large scale after the Eyjafjallajökull eruption for instance). For Turkey, citizens of many countries can get an e-visa online after paying a fee. Trying to enter the country without a passport is much less likely to work.

Comment: @greyshade At Heathrow, you would be granted an emergency entry clearance when they close the international transit zone. The only exception would be really high risk individuals, they basically lock you in an office overnight, but they rarely want to do that, because detaining people who haven't done anything wrong is not really allowed. [However, very high risk individuals will not be given an airside transit visa anyway, precisely to avoid this scenario.] Obviously if you don't have a passport, that would make it very hard to document you.